# Rename base DN in OpenLDAP

Tags: openldap

I currently have an LDAP directory (OpenLDAP), which does authentication for a bunch of services running across a number of servers.

Let's say the base DN is dc=oldcompany,dc=com.

I'd now like to change that to dc=newcompany,dc=com with minimal downtime on services that depend on it.

Is there some way of setting up an "alias" or something so that my services can access the directory through both the old and new DN while I'm reconfiguring everything?

What other alternatives should I consider?  Is there any good documentation around for others doing such a rename?  My Google-foo is failing to find anything.

Comment: In the past, I've had to resort to exporting the entire directory to an ldif file, performing a search-and-replace over the file, and then re-importing. Ugly, but works. I'm unsure if there's a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This kind of operation is not well-supported.

If it were me doing it, I would establish a change window, do a full export of everything using `slapcat` (the output will be in LDIF), use sed to rebase the data (something like `sed -i 's/dc=oldcompany,dc=com/dc=newcompany,dc=com/g' backupfile`), import the data to a new LDAP server, and then replace the old LDAP server with the new one.

There isn't really an equivalent to DNS's DNAME record in LDAP.  Conceptually, referrals could be used to do this, but I don't see that use in the standard ([RFC3296](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3296.txt)), and I'm not sure the results of having both data and a referral under a DN is defined.  Moreover, even if that were to work you'd still eventually have a cutover and minimal ability to test, so you should not do this and cut over as above instead.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this weird error "(line=1): (64) value of single-valued naming attribute 'dc' conflicts with value present in entry" with the sed command

```
sed -i 's/dc=oldcompany,dc=com/dc=newcompany,dc=com/g' backupfile
```

When i switched to just the specific things it fixed my formatting issue which caused that weird error.

```
sed -i -e "s|dc=$backup_dc,dc=com|dc=$current_dc,dc=com|g" -e "s|^dc: $backup_dc|dc: $current_dc|g" -e "s|^o: $backup_dc|o: $current_dc|g" backup.ldif
```